# Angular controller has a unexpected token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax-error

So I have a angular controller file where I keep all my controllers.

If I have this code at the bottom of a controller to only print out a part of my object array. Works fine until I put a new controller after the current one, then non of my views are rendered and I get the following error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

This is the section of code I have that the error if referring to.

```
 $scope.formats = [];

    $scope.productTypeChange = function () {
        $scope.formats = $scope.productsandformats.find(ps = > ps.name == $scope.formData.Product.name
    )
    }
```

Is there a easy way to fix this, when ive looked at stck and google but can seem to find answer.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error itself tells **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >**. You have space between the arrow operator

```
$scope.formats = [];

$scope.productTypeChange = function () {
    $scope.formats = $scope.productsandformats.find(ps => ps.name == $scope.formData.Product.name
)
```

Check [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more details.